# Android studio installation issue : ./studio.sh: 186: ./studio.sh: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java: not found

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio, jvm

I'm new to Android. While executing studio.h to install Android studio I encountered the following error.

```
./studio.sh: 186: ./studio.sh: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java: not found
```

I have followed the steps as updated in the oracle site and installed Java 1.8.0.

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/
XXXX@XXXX-VPCCW25FG:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin$ ls -l java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 XXXX XXXX 5730 Jun 22 15:16 java
```

I have even added the path details in the `/etc/environment` file as well. But still having the issue.

```
$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/media/sailesh/AEB21180B2114DE9/android/android-studio/bin"
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Request someone to help on this. Thanks!

Comment: what are you getting for `java -version` from the user you used to launch `studio.sh`

Comment: $ java -version
bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: Issue resolved. Followed steps as suggested in http://askubuntu.com/questions/634024/bash-usr-bin-java-no-such-file-or-directory. Thanks

Comment: It seems Java did not install correctly, for the java -version command it should output the java version installed. Try re-installing java.